# How do I get rid of the static graph from matplotlib.animation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Here's the code that produces an animation using `matplotlib`. When I run it in Jupyter notebook, I also get another static graph below the animated graph. How do I remove it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from IPython.display import HTML

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
ax.scatter(x, x + np.random.normal(0, 3.0, len(x)))
line, = ax.plot(x, x - 5, 'r-', linewidth=2)

def update(i):
    label = 'timestep {0}'.format(i)
    line.set_ydata(x - 5 + i)
    ax.set_xlabel(label)
    return line, ax

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(0, 10), interval=200)
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

Comment: have you fixed the issue? I'm having exactly the same issue but the answer below doesn't appear to help.

Answer (score 0):

I use a module called `JSAnimation` (see [this example notebook from the Author](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/JSAnimation/blob/master/animation_example.ipynb)).
To display the animation, you simply call:

```
from JSAnimation.IPython_display import display_animation
display_animation(anim)
```